# I cannot exit with EOFerror, and hence the program continues endlessly

Tags: python, loops, except

I am trying to do the following:

- Get input from the user
- Create a list from the input (only if this an original one)
- Sort the list alphabetically
- Once the user exit the program, print out the list in capital letters, with each item being numbered from first to last.

I have the following code:

```
x = input("give me the list: ").capitalize()

#I take the input and put it in all caps

while True:
    try:
        z = [""]
        if x in z:
            z = z
        else:
            z.append(x)
        z.sort()

#as long as the user inputs, I keep adding items to the list. If the item is in the list I do not add it, if it I add it

    except EOFError:
        for i in z:
            a = 0
            a =+ 1
            print(a, i)

#when the user exit the program, I print the item of the list one by one, with a number in front of the item 

    break
```

Instead of getting such a result, I am stuck and cannot exit the program. I keep being asked for inputs.

For example I write: "apple", and I am then asked again and again, even if U press control-d.

Why?

Comment: There is nothing inside the loop that can possibly raise an `EOFError` exception. So the loop is infinite.

Comment: Thank you. But I thought that the EOFError would be "naturally" raised by the "control-d"? What is missing?

Comment: `input` raises `EOFError`; you are only calling it once, *outside* the `try` statement and outside the loop.

Comment: The *only* thing that needs to be in the `try` block is the call to `input`. If `EOFError` is raised, break out of the lop. Otherwise, update `z`. *After* the loop, you can count the items in `z` (if that's what your current exception handler is doing).

Comment: OK, many thanks. I do not understand fully, but I will try to progress in that direction

Comment: What OS?  On Windows, Ctrl-D does nothing but Ctrl-Z will create EOF.

Comment: It's stated this is an exercise, but personally would use an empty item (just hit `Enter`) and use `if not x: break` to exit the while loop and not use `try/except`.

Comment: ok...so Ctrl-D does nothing on Windows...my god I was not aware...thanks @MarkTolonen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case the EOFError needs to be a part of the program, here's a code that might help.

```
z = []
t=0
def f():
  global t
  while t==0:
    global z
    x = input("enter values:")
    x = x.capitalize()
    if x in z:
        z = z
    else:
        z.append(x)
    try:
        p = input("do u want to insert more values?(y/n) ") 
        if p=="y":
            f()
        else:
            z.sort()
            print(z)
            t=1
    except EOFError:
        z.sort()
        print(z)
        t=1
f()
```

As EOFError is generally used when input is not provided, this program will take a blank input as "no" and print the list.
hope this helped :)

Comment: Many thanks, I will try to apply this!

Answer (score 1):

The EOFerror can be avoided completely if the program is done without the while loop as a whole, by defining a recursive function for the same.

```py
z = []

def f():
    global z
    x = input("enter values:")
    x = x.capitalize()
    if x in z:
        z = z
    else:
        z.append(x)
    p = input("do u want to insert more values? (Y / N) ")
    if p == "Y":
        f()
    else:
        z.sort()
        print(z)


f()
```

hope it helped :)

Comment: Many thanks! It does indeed work! However, I need to use "Try" and "EOFerror" as part of the exercise (in order to improve on these notions).

Comment: This is not a great example of recursion, and will end up repeatedly printing `z`.

Comment: I do think my previous code had the correct indentation for print(). If we put print() outside else statement it's gonna print the list numerous time according to the no. of elements present as it's under the for loop. This doesn't happen if print is kept under else statement.

Comment: Using recursion as a sort-of "goto" start of function is not a good idea.  That's what a while loop is for.